# How do I find corrupted PDF files?

Tags: pdf, file-corruption

I have over 100,000 .pdf files. Among them I need to find out the corrupted files.

Is there a way to get the files which are corrupted – or vice versa, get those that are working (in an automated way rather than manually examining the files one at a time)?

I searched a lot but could not find any. All the results were showing me software to fix broken PDFs.

Comment: What's your definition of corrupted? Unreadable by Adobe Reader? Zero pages long? ...

Comment: Yes, that cant be open with adobe reader.

Comment: Maybe also loosely related: [How do I find and remove corrupt images from directory?](https://superuser.com/q/562886/150988)  and [Automating the scanning of graphics files for corruption](https://superuser.com/q/276154/150988).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like Ghostscript to read them all and convert them to bitmap images which are not written to a file (e.g. on Linux redirect output to /dev/null). A script could check for return codes and error messages.