# Successful data recovery but most files are corrupted

Tags: windows-7, backup, data-recovery, restore

I used Recuva and EASEUS Data Recovery Wizard to see if there's any difference in the files they recover. Both software were able to recover files that I want however most of the files where no longer usable. For example, for images, when you view them it's just black, for .doc files, MS Word can no longer open open them. They appear to be corrupted. This happens on both Recuva and EASEUS.

Is there a way I can fix the recovered files or, is there a better recovery software that doesn't "corrupt" files?

Comment: Getting back corrupt files doesn't sound like a "successful" recovery to me!

Comment: @afrazier You are right :-) What I mean with successful is most files were recovered with the correct file names only some were corrupted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Summary

Sadly no.

## Technical Details

What happened was that those files were fragmented, and once they were deleted, the cluster chain was removed, so when the programs "recovered" them, what they did was to look at the starting location (which is still present) and the size of the file (which is also still present) and simply copied that many clusters in a row from the start.

This works fine if the files are stored in a single, contiguous block (i.e., defragmented), but if they were fragmented, then their blocks are spread out around the disk and the program has absolutely no way to know where/which ones to use; that's why most of the corrupted recovered files will have at least one cluster's worth of correct data, but then contain whatever happened to be in the subsequent clusters that used to belong to other files.

If the files are plain-text, then you *could* search the drive for unused clusters (which is a nightmare with a giant, nearly empty disk) and manually stitch the file back together (I did this a few times many years ago). But with binary files, this is effectively impossible. In fact, even with plain-text files, it is difficult *at best* if the file had been getting edited and saved after changes numerous times because it then becomes difficult to identify the clusters that contain blocks of the last version of the file.

## PhotoRec (and its ilk)

As you noticed, PhotoRec seems to recover more (at the cost of lost filenames). I'll explain.

The above explanation is how some data-recovery programs work. It is generally more reliable because it looks at real files that existed more recently. However (not surprisingly perhaps), it can miss out on some files. That is why other programs like PhotoRec use a different approach. Instead of looking at a *deleted* file's information (filename, size, timestamp, starting cluster) in directory entry and then copying the clusters from the disk, they search the whole disk for *lost* files.

Most file types have a signature (usually at the start of the file, in the header) which contains a sequence of bytes that identify the file as a certain type. Because of this, programs that open a file can determine if the file is teh correct type and other programs can verify the type of a file.

What some data-recovery programs do is to search the disk and check each cluster to see if they contain the signature of various different file types. If a cluster contains a signature, then it copies that cluster (and more depending on various factors) to a file.

This means that it can find some files that are not linked in any directories. That's good, but there are some downsides:

- Because it searches the disk directly instead of directory entries, it has no information about the file, so it applies a generic filename, and gives it the current date/time for the timestamp instead of the file's original one
- Because it has no information about the file, it does not know how big the file is supposed to be. Some (few?) filetypes indicate the exact size in the header, so most of the files that are recovered will, at best, be rounded up to the nearest cluster while others can end up being ridiculously huge (e.g., a 10x10 GIF file that is 1.7GB!)
- Like with the other data-recovery method, it has no way of recovering fragmented files and only copies contiguous (unused) clusters regardless of whether they belong to the file or not (check the files that PhotoRec recovered; plenty will be half-corrupt like the ones that Recuva recovered
- Because it is manually scanning the disk, it will "recover" a whole lot more files than programs that use the other method; many of these files are legitimately deleted files that may have been erased a long time ago, and they also come from all over the disk, not just a specific directory. This means a lot more clutter and more files that have to be examined and sorted through. The problem is that

## Sympathy/Commiseration

I was in a similar situation to yours last year. I accidentally deleted ~9,000 graphic files from a volume that was nearly full (hence lots of fragmentation) I used a host of recovery programs that gave (sometimes vastly) different results. While I got a lot of files back, not surprisingly, many of them were corrupt and more than a year later, I'm [still trying to sort through them](https://superuser.com/questions/276154/automating-the-scanning-of-graphics-files-for-corruption) and find which ones are bad.

Unfortunately, current file-systems still don't do much to enhance data-recovery, so losing files means a lot of manual work.

## Advice

It doesn't help *after* losing files, but for future reference, the best way to increase the chances of a successful recovery is to keep the disk defragmented (have the system automatically defragment when it idles).

Comment: Thank you for the sympathy :-) I found a program named PhotoRec http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec which appears to recover everything even some corrupt files (not all of course). The only downside is the file names are messed-up. Maybe that can help you.

Comment: Unfortunately PhotoRec has its own problems. I've edited the question to explain.

Comment: You are right. Sorting through PhotoRec's recovered files is a real pain. Although, it's better than nothing. I guess it's the last resort.

Comment: I used a dozen different programs when I lost those 9,000 files last year. I figured that between them all, I would be able to get most of most of the files. Sadly, over a year later, I still have to sort through over 45,000 files that I "recovered" (and this is **after** deleting duplicate files from the recovery directory).

Comment: Thank you @IMB and Synetech . I lost my files on my SD Card, and GetDataBack couldn't recover my photos. (They were broken). But now it seems that PhotoRec is making some progress. It's slow, but it has found a few of my photos after a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I'll answer.

I know this is an old OP, non the less people find it and will read it and will be discouraged by the answer.

I disagree with the up-voted answer because I can think of an have come across situations where data that could not be recovered by popular tools like Recuva and Easeus were actually recoverable.

These are popular tools but not the best. There is no one best tool, however there are better tools to try before giving up.

So, yes, fragmentation can be an issue when recovering data but is not by definition. For example, it depends highly on the file system you are recovering data from. It also depends on how the data was lost.

For example, assume a formatted volume and we'll compare FAT based FS vs. NTFS: Yes, in the FAT based FS (FAT32, exFAT) fragmented files are an issue because the file allocation tables were wiped during the format. On NTFS most MFT entries will survive and as long we have those fragmented file recovery is no issue at all as we have the complete runlists for the files.

Example 2: a RAW volume. This can be caused by major file system corruption but also by something as simple as a corrupted boot sector BIOS parameter block. If the latter on both FAT32, exFAT and NTFS volume you should be able to achieve a close to 100% perfect recovery, fragmented files or not. However the reason that popular tools like Recuva and Easeus often fail in these situations are that they're not that good in working out a valid virtual file system.

Then one remark about software that scans for file signatures, or 'carvers'. It is true that for many files it is not possible to detect a file end so you potentially end up with huge files. However there's plenty of files that you can detect file ends for + there a number of rules of thumb you could apply here too.

There are tools specifically designed to puzzle together fragmented files even with absence of any valid file system structures. However, they often work only for very specific file types, such as JPEG, or MP4 or XLS. The reason for this being they need specialized 'knowledge' about the actual file structure to reconstruct valid files.

So the 'Sadly no.' in the upvoted answer isn't true by definition.