# How to find usable files among recovered files?

Tags: data-recovery

When you use a data recovery program like Recuva, it can "recover" lots of files which lots of them are just unusable with random data in them but somehow having correct filenames. Is there any way to automatically detect those files or files having meaningful data but needing repairs and delete the rest of the files which are junk?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but may be useful: https://superuser.com/q/432535/432690 .

Comment: @confetti I was looking for a way to do it in Windows as I'm not too much familiar with Linux unfortunately. But I marked it and thank you.

Comment: @confetti There's a Windows program called TrID File Identifier and it works great and also has a command line feature. Do you think we can write a simple program to automate checking every files in a directory by TrID? Here's the [link](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) to the program.

Comment: I found http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm this, which claims to be "File for windows". Maybe that is a help. TrID looks great for the job, but I can't find a way to output only the extension or mime-type. Another idea would be to use a live linux distribution on an USB stick. It's really quick, doesn't change anything on your system (runs from USB) and after you ran my script you can switch back to windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under linux, the utility `file` might be worth looking into. It "tests" each file you pass to it using three different kind of tests instead of relying on the filename's extension. (See `man file` for an explanation of the different tests).

Here's an approach for testing every file in a directory and copying it into a new folder if it's a JPEG image.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

mkdir useful

for cfile in *; do
    fileres=$(file -b --mime-type "${cfile}")
    if [[ "${fileres}" == "image/jpeg" ]]; then
        cp "${cfile}" "useful/"
    fi
done
```

Run this script in the directory with all your recovered files, and it will copy only jpeg files to the `useful` directory. If you're looking for other filetypes simply replace the `image/jpeg` in my script with the mime-type of the files you are interested in.