# How to undelete a file on JFS

Tags: filesystems, jfs

How can I recover a deleted file on JFS? It was deleted from inside Emacs/dired but I think it just uses rm. I have searched the Arch repository, AUR and searched the web but I find nothing.

Comment: Testdisk might help. If not you probably have to dig into [file recovery](https://superuser.com/a/1347139/926024).

Comment: Thank you but testdisk does not undelete files on JFS.