# Recovering lost partitions

Tags: data-recovery, partition-recovery

I faced a problem: Windows couldn't start at all. After connecting the hard disk to another PC only about 3GB is there, the actual size is 1TB.

Is there any way to recover lost partitions ?

[image: Check This Image]

Comment: For data recovery, just in case: https://superuser.com/a/1347139/926024 - I'm going to leave a full answer with another approach you can try to recover the partitions in a bit but if you have enough free space on **another** drive you should make a full backup (as an image-file, see step 1 in my linked answer) before doing anything else to prevent further damage.

Comment: You may want to have a look at photorec / testdisk for recovering files, in case the partition cannot be fixed in other ways.

Comment: Was it a MBR or GPT partition table? GPT should have a backup copy, so a single read error shouldn't be a deal breaker. And how is the drive connected to the second PC, direct to sata, or through a usb adapter? If an adapter, did the same drive previously work on the same PC with the same adapter? Sometimes adapters act funny. What do the SMART data/tests say? +1 to testdisk/photorec, they're not trials, they're 100% free & open source (GPL2)

Answer (score 0):

The cyclic redundancy error means that there is a bad sector.
Normally this isn't a serious error except for the at most one involved file,
but in your case this is apparently happening in the disk header and is falsifying
the published properties of the disk.

If there is data on the disk to which there is no backup, you may try to use
a free utility to recover it. Some such are :

- [EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard Free](https://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/free-data-recovery-software.htm)
  will recover up to 2GB for free.
- [MiniTool Power Data Recovery Free](https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery-software/free-for-windows.html)
  (I don't know the limits for the free version)

After the data is recovered, you may deep-format the disk for reuse,
but remain suspicious of it and keep backups.

You should also in the future keep an eye on the S.M.A.R.T. indicators
of the disk, by using a utility such as
[Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy).

Answer (score 0):

You should give [Testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) a try. It runs under Windows too.

1. Start it as administrator
2. Hit `[ Create ]`
3. Select your disk and hit `[Proceed ]`
4. Select your partition table type (usually `Intel` or `GPT`)
5. Hit `[ Analyse ]` followed by `[Quick Search]`
6. Assuming that doesn't find everything, hit <kbd>Return</kbd> to continue
7. Hit `[Deeper Search]` and wait until it's done
8. After that hit <kbd>Return</kbd> to continue and then `[Write]` to write partition table to disk

If that works you should have your partitions and files right there again. If it doesn't you have to do file recovery. I wrote an extensive tutorial on that topic [in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1347139/926024).

**If data is important: I urge you to, before you perform any steps, create a full backup of your drive at its current state to prevent further damage. (Step 1 in my linked tutorial)**