# Identify corrupt photos in Photos.app

Tags: photos, jpeg, file-corruption

What is the best approach to identify all corrupt JPGs managed with Photos.app (formerly known as iPhoto) for macOS?

Basically, this is the same question as [posed previously](https://superuser.com/q/276154/287154), but specifically for Apple's photo management app.

Rationale: In my case, I have some 80.000 photos. Due to the library size I would appreciate an approach that does not include exporting all the images before scanning. Also, inside Photos.app there are thumbnails that are intact, which could potentially serve as "hinting" for any software that can restore the photos.

I am aware that the `.photoslibrary` “file” technically is a directory packaged as a [bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_(macOS)), but due to the specialised nature of the directory, I am hesitant to run scanners inside it without guidance. However, if e.g. someone has used [Bad Peggy](https://superuser.com/a/1083216/287154) to scan the originals inside the bundle, it would be great to learn from their experiences, as this app does indeed discover the corrupted files.

<sup>(I am aware that there is an Apple specific site on StackExchange, but I prefer SuperUser for this topic since the answers here are more thorough [than on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/274866/57188))</sup>